# convert decimal to hex then do hex math

Tags: c, hex

How would you go about converting a decimal value to hex and then do math in C programming? Every example of converting decimal to hex that I have seen creates an array and I wouldn't be able to do math if I did that. Something like this. 
I just want the basic idea of how to do hex math C. I have mixed files that I'm reading from. Part of the files are in hex and part are in decimal. So first step is to convert the decimal to hex. You obviously can't do math hex and decimal without converting one of them. I wanna convert the decimal to hex. The only 2 ways to convert that I have found is to make an array which you can't do math with a char array and the %x option with printf and then you can't do math that way

```
15 decimal to hex F
17 decimal to hex 11
F hex + 11 hex = 20
```

Comment: its not entirely clear what you are asking - do you want to read an input from the user in hex, do some math, and then output? If not I am confused, since the base is just a display issue. Internally, its just a number.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question, since it is confused. All integers in a computer are in binary format. All calculations are done in binary format. Decimal and hex are just two ways to represent the binary numbers to humans. It doesn't make any sense to convert from one representation to another. Simply represent the numbers in the form which is most convenient.

Comment: I just want the basic idea of how to do hex math C. I have mixed files that I'm reading from. Part of the files are in hex and part are in decimal. So first step is to convert the decimal to hex. You obviously can't do math hex and decimal without converting one of them. I wanna convert the decimal to hex. The only 2 ways to convert that I have found is to make an array which you can't do math with a char array and the %x option with printf and then you can't do math that way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Decimal or hex are just representation of the number in a form human readable. I mean: internal number representation is always the same, but when you `printf` or `scanf` you probably want to use some rule to make things easy to read by an user. So there is not exactly the concept or 'conversion' but there is better a *formatting* and  *parsing* strategies.
To show a number in hex, you can for example use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int data = 29;
    printf("%x\n", data);    // just print data
    printf("%8x\n", data);   // print in 8 width and pad with blank spaces
    printf("%08x\n", data);  // print in 8 width and pad with 0's


}
```

if you want the inverse, ie you have a text representation of the number in an hex format, you can for example write:

```
int value;
sscanf("FF","%x",&value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally it's all done in binary, but you can present it however you'd like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a = 15;
  int b = 17;
  int c = a + b;
  printf("%x + %x = %x\n",a,b,c);
  return 0;
}
```